# Why may certificate price be substantially below commodity price?

Tags: price, commodities

The Brent Crude oil certificate [NL0000202109](http://markets.rbs.com/EN/Showpage.aspx?pageID=10&isin=NL0000202109) currently has a value of ca. 26.50 EUR, whereas the price of the commodity is at 48 USD, a substantial difference. I would expect the certificate's value to be about the same as that of the commodity.

*Can someone explain the huge difference in price?*

[image: Screenshot of price as of 2015-01-26 WET]

Comment: According to the info on that page and in the [Find out more](http://markets.rbs.com/EN/Showpage.aspx?pageID=25&isin=NL0000202109) link on the right, it sounds like these `certificates` are priced arbitrarily relative to the underlying instrument. This certificate appears to be priced around 62% of the underlying instrument. But I've never heard of certificates before, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: @dg99 *Arbitrary pricing* could be the explanation. However, why would the issuer do that? It's confusing to me, and I'm worried that I don't understand an important aspect of that certificate, or certificates in general.

Comment: Yes, I imagine the pricing is spelled out in the fine print somewhere, but I couldn't find said fine print on that page.